# Count two different child row conditions at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `Request` and Table `Search`. The `Request` table has an ID column, which is a foreign key in `Search` as RequestID. There can  be multiple rows in `Search` with the same RequestID. There's another column in `Search`, Status, which can be either Complete or Incomplete. What I want is a query that returns for each RequestID:

`RequestID` - `Count of Search rows with 'Complete'` - `Count of Search rows with 'Incomplete'`

Is this something that can be done easily with SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try :

```
SELECT RequestId,
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Incomplete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Search
GROUP BY RequestId
```

If you want to list every RequestId even if there was no search done on this request, you can do :

```
SELECT r.Id,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.Status = 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
SUM(CASE WHEN s.Status = 'Incomplete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Request r
LEFT JOIN Search s ON r.Id = s.RequestId
GROUP BY r.Id
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/663e5/1/0)

Comment: And in the case there are no `Search` rows you can add converting the NULL results to 0s.

Comment: Hmm I don't think that matters in this case. I'm fairly certain every request is guaranteed to have at least one search, or a request isn't generated. Thanks though, your answer helped a lot. SQL definitely isn't my first language